# agergar a una lista lo que esta en color verda

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, dataset

Quiero agregar a una lista las filas pintadas en color verde, ver imagen.

Este es mi codigo VB con el que pinto las filas, ahora como puedo agregar a una lista o un dataset?
Al hacer doble click sobre el folio y si el folio se repite entonces quiero pasarlo a una lista o un dataset.

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        fol = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString()
        idPro = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        tprov = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(9).Value.ToString()
        provedor = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(10).Value.ToString()
        TextBox1.Text = fol

        fol = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        Dim repetidos As String() = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().[Select](Function(x) Convert.ToString(x.Cells(0).Value)).ToArray()
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        While i < repetidos.Length

            For Each item As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

                If fol = repetidos(i) Then
                    item.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                Else
                    item.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
                End If

                i += 1
            Next
        End While

    End If
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con un For i Next

Ejemplo;

```
For i = 0 To Datagrid1.Rows.Count - 1
    If Datagrid.row(i).cell(0).style.backcolor = color.green Then
         Dataset.add(Datagrid.row(i).cell(0), Datagrid.row(i).cell(1), Datagrid.row(i).cell(2))
    Endif
```

Next

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Si bien tú respuesta puede ser apropiada, quizá explicar el porqué de la solución apoyaría a quién a preguntado y a otros usuarios que lleguen a esta pregunta. Puede serte de interés leer [answer].